# How to pipe output of sass --watch to autoprefixer?

Tags: sass, command-line-interface, autoprefixer

I have a build command for my Sass styles like this:

`sass src/styles/main.scss --style compressed | autoprefixer -b \"> 1%, IE 8\" > dist/main.css`

Now, I would like to have a similar command for the developement process. But I can't figure out how to pipe the files changed by `sass --watch` to the autoprefixer cli. I managed to get around it with [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) tool for OSX but I hope for an easier and more universal solutiond

Comment: What did you find out here? I've been trying to watch a dir and pipe those files to autoprefixer but finding clear examples is tough. Just using gulp for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)? It would be really easy to do what you want with the `gulp-sass` and `gulp-autoprefixer` node packages.

Something like this in your `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var sass         = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('scss', function() {
    return gulp.src('path/to/styles.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/css'))
});
```